# Android Studio code style settings warning after update

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio from version 3.0 to 3.1, this warning appeared :

> The code style settings of your project projectName were migrated to
>   the new format. We're keeping the old format for now, for backwards
>   compatibility.

Do I have to change something (and where) in my configuration?

Comment: why would you have to change something?

Comment: to change the code style. If I understand, a new format is now used, but my old one keeps stored anywhere.

Comment: Add _gradle_ snippet for more clarification. Thanks